# extend a pandas datetimeindex by 1 period

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

consider the `DateTimeIndex` `dates`

```
dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-29', periods=4, freq='BM')
dates

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-29', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

I want to extend the index by one period at the frequency attached to the object.

---

I expect

```
pd.date_range('2016-01-29', periods=5, freq='BM')

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-29', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-29',
               '2016-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

---

I've tried

```
dates.append(dates[[-1]] + pd.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd())
```

However

- Not generalized to use frequency of `dates`
- I get a performance warning

  > PerformanceWarning: Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The timestamps in your `DatetimeIndex` already know that they are describing business month ends, so you can simply add 1:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-29', periods=4, freq='BM')

print(repr(dates[-1]))
# => Timestamp('2016-04-29 00:00:00', offset='BM')

print(repr(dates[-1] + 1))
# => Timestamp('2016-05-31 00:00:00', offset='BM')
```

You can add the latter to your index using `.union`:

```
dates = dates.union([dates[-1] + 1])
print(dates)
# => DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-29', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-29',
#                   '2016-05-31'],
#                  dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

Compared to `.append`, this retains knowledge of the offset.

Comment: Very nice and neat solution!

Comment: If you wish to extend the index out by `n` periods, you can use `dates.union(pd.date_range(dates[-1]+1, periods=n, freq=dates.freq))`

Comment: This is now deprecated.
Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays to Timestamp is deprecated, will be removed in a future version.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * self.freq`

Answer (score 7):

## pandas==1.1.1 Answer for +1

To follow up on this, for `pandas==1.1.1`, I found this to be the best solution:

`dates.union(pd.date_range(dates[-1] + dates.freq, periods=1, freq=dates.freq))`

## Generalised Answer Using n

```
n=3
dates.union(pd.date_range(dates[-1] + dates.freq, periods=n, freq=dates.freq))
```

## Credits

Taken by combining @alberto-garcia-raboso's answer and @ballpointben's comment.

## What Didn't Work

- The following just got formatted to an `Index`, not a `DateTimeIndex`:
  `dates.union([dates[-1] + dates.freq])`
- Also `dates[-1] + 1` is deprecated.

Comment: `+ dates.freq` wasn't working consistently for me, although this worked:
`dates.union(pd.date_range(dates[-1], periods=(n + 1), freq=dates.freq)[1:])`

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-29', periods=4, freq='BM')
extended = dates.union(dates.shift(n)[-n:])
```

where n is the number of periods you want to add. With `n=4`, you will get an extended date range like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-29', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-29',
               '2016-05-31', '2016-06-30', '2016-07-29', '2016-08-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [207]: dates = dates.append(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(dates[-1] + pd.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd())))

In [208]: dates
Out[208]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-29', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-29', '2016-05-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

or using `list` (`[...]`) instead of `pd.Series()`:

```
In [211]: dates.append(pd.DatetimeIndex([dates[-1] + pd.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd()]))
Out[211]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-29', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-29', '2016-05-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `.tshift` function and then use accordingly:

```
dr = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], 
                  index=dr,
                  columns=['A'])
df.head()
            A
2020-01-01  1
2020-01-02  2
2020-01-03  3
2020-01-04  4
2020-01-05  5 <-

df.tshift()
            A
2020-01-02  1
2020-01-03  2
2020-01-04  3
2020-01-05  4
2020-01-06  5 <-

other = pd.DataFrame([6], columns=['A'], index=[df.tshift().index[-1]])
other.head()
            A
2020-01-06  6

df.append(other)
            A
2020-01-01  1
2020-01-02  2
2020-01-03  3
2020-01-04  4
2020-01-05  5
2020-01-06  6 <-
```

Comment: It seems tshift is deprecated since version 1.1.0. I suggest using fccoelho's answer.