# add 10 step at the end of a datetimeindex

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

I creat a df with datetimeindex like this

```
index                               value
2020-03-04T16:00:00.000000000        5
2020-03-04T16:05:00.000000000        8
2020-03-04T16:10:00.000000000        4
2020-03-04T16:15:00.000000000        1
```

I want to extend the range of my df by adding 10 rows at the end with respecting the 5min step

I try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516671/extend-a-pandas-datetimeindex-by-1-period), with no success

Comment: What will the values be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_range` for new `DatetimeIndex` by maximal `index` with next `5 minutes` and then use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
r = pd.date_range(df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(5, 'Min'), freq='5Min', periods=10)

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=r), sort=True)
print (df)
                     value
2020-03-04 16:00:00    5.0
2020-03-04 16:05:00    8.0
2020-03-04 16:10:00    4.0
2020-03-04 16:15:00    1.0
2020-03-04 16:20:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:25:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:30:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:35:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:40:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:45:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:50:00    NaN
2020-03-04 16:55:00    NaN
2020-03-04 17:00:00    NaN
2020-03-04 17:05:00    NaN
```

If need specify value:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'value': 0}, index=r), sort=True)
print (df)
                     value
2020-03-04 16:00:00      5
2020-03-04 16:05:00      8
2020-03-04 16:10:00      4
2020-03-04 16:15:00      1
2020-03-04 16:20:00      0
2020-03-04 16:25:00      0
2020-03-04 16:30:00      0
2020-03-04 16:35:00      0
2020-03-04 16:40:00      0
2020-03-04 16:45:00      0
2020-03-04 16:50:00      0
2020-03-04 16:55:00      0
2020-03-04 17:00:00      0
2020-03-04 17:05:00      0
```