# Appending a data frame index doesn't work properly

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append a data frame index if certain condition is met, apparently when I print the append everything is looking right and the code is working. But when I look at the data frame index after leaving the if there is no appended value in there even if the condition was met.

```
if (year_and_month not in to_dashboard.index):
    print("I'm appending the index")
    new_index = pd.Index([year_and_month])
    print(new_index)
    to_dashboard.index.append(new_index)
    print(to_dashboard.index)
```

And there is the if output:

I am appending the index :

```
Index(['2022-08'], dtype='object')

Index(['2022-05', '2022-06', '2022-07'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: `to_dashboard.reindex(to_dashboard.index.union(year_and_month))`?

Comment: It's still not appending

Comment: maybe index expanding will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516671/extend-a-pandas-datetimeindex-by-1-period